# call a level-2 sfunction via the matlab editor

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

**I have developped a simulink model. I compiled it to have a level-2 sfunction  : 'sfun.mexw32'. 
I would like to call this sfunction in a .m file in the Matlab editor.**

I struggle with how to implement it, so I am first trying to understand how to do that with an illustration sfunction already existing in matlab : *timestwo*.

You can get more information by typing `open('sfuntmpl.m')` which is the template for sfunction.

```
[sys,x0,str,ts] =timestwo(0,0,1,3)
```

I got this error : 
*"Error using timestwo
MEX level2 S-function "timestwo" called with too many left hand arguments"*

I do not understand why I have this error, and I expected to have the result of the input `1` which should be `2`.

And also know if it is possible to give a vector of input and an input representing time to simulate a signal and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your s-function has a `.mexw32` extension then it is a compiled Level-2 C-code S-function.  It is **not** an m-code S-function.

I think that you'll find that there is no possible way to call either a Level-2 M-code S-function, or a Level-2 C-code S-function from anything other than a Simulink model.  A level-2 m-code S-function has one input, which is a `block` object created and passed to it by the Simulink execution engine, while a level-2 c-code S-function is comprised of a number of functions each of which is passed a `simStruct` (c-code) structure, which is also created by the Simulink execution engine.

You would have to create a model with your S-function in it, presumably along with the appropriate `inport` and `outport` blocks, then use `sim` to call the model.

Note that the link you give (i.e. `open('sfuntmpl.m')`) is to the template for a ***Level-1*** m-code S-function.  These can be called from MATLAB as they are *just* a regular m-code function.  ***If*** you have a Level-1 m-code S-function (which it appears you do not) then you should be able to call it in the way that you are trying to do in the question.

The template for a level-2 m-code S-function is: `edit('msfuntmpl.m');`

The template for a level-2 c-code S-function is: `edit(fullfile(matlabroot,'simulink','src','sfuntmpl_basic.c'));`